# Use lemon parser(LALR) generate a calulator, how to get param from expressions

Tags: c, sqlite, lemon

I want to get param from a input. For example: `Input:12+10`.
After running my calculator.

I want to get 12 and 10. I know, I have to use the fourth param in `Parse(pParser, hTokenID, sTokenData, pArg);`, but how?

**parser.y**:

```
%syntax_error{fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error\n");}
%left PLUS MINUS.
%left TIMES DIVIDE.
program ::= expr(A).{printf("Result = %d\n", A);}
expr(A) ::= expr(B) PLUS expr(C).{A = B + C; }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) MINUS expr(C). {A = B - C; }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) TIMES expr(C). {A = B * C; }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) DIVIDE expr(C). {if (C != 0)A = B / C;else fprintf(stderr,"divide by 0");}
expr(A) ::= LPAR expr(B) RPAR. {A = (B);}
expr(A) ::= INTEGER(B).{A = B;}
```

**calc.c**:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
pParser = (void *)ParseAlloc(malloc);
for (c = argv[1]; *c; c++){
switch (*c){
case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
for (value = 0; *c && *c >= '0' && *c <= '9'; c++)
    value = value * 10 + (*c - '0');
    c--;
    Parse(pParser, INTEGER, value);
    break;
case '+':
    Parse(pParser, PLUS, 0);
    break;
case '-':
    Parse(pParser, MINUS, 0);
    break;
case '*':
    Parse(pParser, TIMES, 0);
    break;
    ...(the rest case I dont write anymore,the same as before)
}
}
Parse(pParser, 0, 0);
ParseFree(pParser, free);
}
```

Comment: sorry, I am a new user, show code failed

Comment: Why do you have this for-loop in the main function? It seems to follow the same goal as the parser itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to pass some data into `lemon`'s blocks through 4-th parameter, you have to add into your `.y` file the following line:

```
%extra_argument { const char* arg }
```

See lemon's documentation (http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/lemon.html):

> **The `%extra_argument` directive**
>
> The `%extra_argument` directive instructs Lemon to add a 4th parameter to the parameter list of the `Parse()` function it generates. Lemon doesn't do anything itself with this extra argument, but it does make the argument available to C-code action routines, destructors, and so forth. For example, if the grammar file contains:
>
> ```
> %extra_argument { MyStruct *pAbc }
> ```
>
> Then the `Parse()` function generated will have an 4th parameter of type `MyStruct*` and all action routines will have access to a variable named `pAbc` that is the value of the 4th parameter in the most recent call to `Parse()`.

But notice that "that is the value of the 4th parameter in the **most recent call** to `Parse()`"

So, I believe that you want to pass exactly token value. In this case you have to wrap token value into structure:

```
struct SToken
{
    int value;
    const char* token;
};
```

Your program modified in this way:

**parse.y**:

```
%include
{
#include "types.h"

#include "assert.h"
}
%syntax_error { fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error\n"); }
%token_type { struct SToken* }
%type expr { int }
%left PLUS MINUS.
%left TIMES DIVIDE.
program ::= expr(A). { printf("Result = %d\n", A); }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) PLUS expr(C). {A = B + C; }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) MINUS expr(C). {A = B - C; }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) TIMES expr(C). {A = B * C; }
expr(A) ::= expr(B) DIVIDE expr(C).
{
    if (C != 0)
    {
        A = B / C;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "divide by 0");
    }
}
expr(A) ::= LPAR expr(B) RPAR. { A = B; }
expr(A) ::= INTEGER(B).
{
    A = B->value;
    printf("Passed argument: %s\n", B->token);
}
```

**main.c**:

```
#include "types.h"
#include "parse.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int value;
    void* pParser;
    const char *c;
    size_t i = 0;
    struct SToken v[argc];

    if (2 > argc)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <expression>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    pParser = (void *) ParseAlloc(malloc);
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        c = argv[i];
        v[i].token = c;
        switch (*c)
        {
            case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
            case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
                for (value = 0; *c && *c >= '0' && *c <= '9'; c++)
                    value = value * 10 + (*c - '0');
                v[i].value = value;
                Parse(pParser, INTEGER, &v[i]);
                break;

            case '+':
                Parse(pParser, PLUS, NULL);
                break;

            case '-':
                Parse(pParser, MINUS, NULL);
                break;

            case '*':
                Parse(pParser, TIMES, NULL);
                break;

            case '/':
                Parse(pParser, DIVIDE, NULL);
                break;

            case '(':
                Parse(pParser, LPAR, NULL);
                break;

            case ')':
                Parse(pParser, RPAR, NULL);
                break;

            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected token %s\n", c);
        }
    }
    Parse(pParser, 0, NULL);
    ParseFree(pParser, free);

    return 0;
}
```

**types.h**:

```
#ifndef __TYPES_H__
#define __TYPES_H__

#include <stdlib.h>

struct SToken
{
    int value;
    const char* token;
};

extern void *ParseAlloc(void *(*)(size_t));
extern void Parse(void *, int, struct SToken*);
void ParseFree(void *, void (*)(void*));

#endif
```

Sample output:

```
veei@sauron:~/tmp/build$ ./test.it
Usage: ./test.it <expression>
veei@sauron:~/tmp/build$ ./test.it 12
Passed argument: 12
Result = 12
veei@sauron:~/tmp/build$ ./test.it 12 + 12
Passed argument: 12
Passed argument: 12
Result = 24
veei@sauron:~/tmp/build$ ./test.it 12 - 12
Passed argument: 12
Passed argument: 12
Result = 0
veei@sauron:~/tmp/build$ ./test.it 12 "*" 12
Passed argument: 12
Passed argument: 12
Result = 144
veei@sauron:~/tmp/build$ ./test.it "(" 12 + 12 ")" "*" 2
Passed argument: 12
Passed argument: 12
Passed argument: 2
Result = 48
veei@sauron:~/tmp/build$ ./test.it "(" 12 "*" 12 ")" "+" 2
Passed argument: 12
Passed argument: 12
Passed argument: 2
Result = 146
veei@sauron:~/tmp/build$ ./test.it 12 / 12
Passed argument: 12
Passed argument: 12
Result = 1
veei@sauron:~/tmp/build$
```

And just in case, CMake script to compile this sample:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(lemon.test)

add_executable(test.it main.c parse.c)

add_custom_target(parser DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/parse.c)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/parse.c COMMAND lemon -s ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/parse.y DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/parse.y)
add_dependencies(test.it parser)
```